In Salesforce FSL, how to create fully empty shell crew in order to display service appointment with unknown service resources?
I have a requirement in salesforce FSL to display appointment in Gant view while technicians of service appointment is yet unknown. Is this possible? Any alternatives or ideas people?
I tried crews but still didn't found the way to create one without single active member as known user.
